# Does the presence of dark matter in the Milky Way significantly distort our parallax based measurements of distance?

Tags: general-relativity, dark-matter, parallax

According to accepted astronomical wisdom, dark matter represents a large fraction of the total mass of the Milky Way.  And thanks to Papa Einstein, we know that light rays can be bent when passing through spacetime distorted by a mass distribution. Thus, does the presence of dark matter in and around our galaxy significantly distort measurements of parallax and the distances calculated therefrom?

Comment: Interesting question. Yet I believe: If it was distorting parallax a lot, it would mean it's clumpy - and that would be well visible in the dynamics of the visible matter on small(er) scales.

Comment: @planetmaker Why does a large distortion imply clumpiness? It just implies a lot of mass which could be either clumpy or evenly distributed.

Comment: @zephyr as the parallax implies the annual variation of the apparent position, a constant distortion of the true position doesn't matter. But the curvature difference must be large enough that it amplifies measurably the apparent position change due to a difference to the light path. Absolute position change due to large-scale masses but low gradients in curvature does not matter.

Comment: @zephyr uniformly distributed dark matter would lead to a net path 'bending' of zero.

Comment: To put it another way, a point source would deflect a photon one way, another point source in the right place would bend it back.  So uniformly distributed mass would attempt to deflect it in every direction, resulting in no deflection.